# How to find the first appearance based on certain criteria

Tags: r

I have the following proxy data and I am using data table.

```
Id         V1       V2
Aa         10      1000
Aa          20       90
Ab          20       90
Ab          20       90
Ab          20       100
As          50       90
As          300     150
As           150     0
```

I want to create another field to mark 1 for the first appearance of each ID in V2 that is greater than 0. Ie see ID Ab, it only gets marked 1 on its second entry.

So like the following:

```
Id         V1       V2          Indicator
Aa         10      1000           1
Aa          20       90              0
Ab          20       0                0
Ab          20       90.             1
Ab          20       100.           0
As          50       90.             1
As          300     150.           0
As           150     0.              0
```

Comment: You really need to make some sort of attempt here, SO is not a code writing service, we're here to help but we're not going to do all the work for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
library( "data.table" )
df6[, id := 1:.N] # create unique row id
df6[, indicator := 0 ]  # assign 0 for all rows of indicator column
# find id values that pass the criteria and assign 1 to indicator column
df6[ id %in% df6[ V2 > 0 & V2 < 10000, .SD[1], by = .(Id)][, id], indicator := -1]
df6[ id %in% df6[ V2 >= 10000, .SD[1], by = .(Id)][, id], indicator := 1]
df6[ , id := NULL ] # remove id column
df6
#    Id  V1      V2 indicator
# 1: Aa  10    1000        -1
# 2: Aa  20      90         0
# 3: Ab  20       0         0
# 4: Ab  20      90        -1
# 5: Ab  20     100         0
# 6: As  50      90        -1
# 7: As 300     150         0
# 8: As 150       0         0
# 9: Ap  10 1000000         1
```

Based on @Jaap's comment:

```
df6[, indicator := 0 ][
  df6[, .I[V2 > 0 & V2 < 10000][1], by = Id]$V1, indicator := -1][
    df6[, .I[V2 >= 10000][1], by = Id]$V1, indicator := 1]
```

Data: I added an extra row with a value more than 10K

```
df6 <- fread('Id         V1       V2
    Aa         10      1000
             Aa          20       90
             Ab          20       0
             Ab          20       90
             Ab          20       100
             As          50       90
             As          300     150
             As           150     0
             Ap         10      1000000', header = TRUE)
```

Comment: or: `df6[, indicator := 0][df6[, .I[V2 > 0][1], by = Id]$V1, indicator := 1][]`

Comment: Thanks for that. That actually worked. How would that vary if I wanted to use this for a similar sort of thing, but I have now 2 conditions.i.e say this is the data: I want 1 if V2 > 10000, but if V2 ever comes back below 10k then -1.                                                                                                      id V1             V2 Indicator
Aa  1,000   1,000    0
Aa  9,800   10,800    1
Ab  1,500   1,500    0
Ab  30000   31500    1
Ab  1000        32500      0
Ab -30000   2500   -1
As  1,200   1,200   0
As  14,000   15,200   1
As   0           15,200    0